# How to disable Gmail Print's NEW [Quoted text hidden]?

Tags: gmail

Since an apparent recent change to Gmail, Print performs [Quoted text hidden]
even on text that **does not show the inline unhide button** (defeating the previous
workaround). Any workaround in Gmail?

Perhaps the effect is limited to certain conditions by e.g. Gmail's flaky quoted text detection examination of up-conversation messages.

This issue seems recent because web shows very few reports as yet. And no solutions.

Failed workarounds:

1. Use a different client: most unsatisfactory since I'm printing to PDF for an archive where consistency is important.
2. Take to attached message: defeated by Gmail's attached message display's omission of the Print command:

   1. Download the message (as .EML).
   2. Send a new message to self including that .EML attached.
   3. Open received message & open its attachment.
   4. Tolerate this Gmail message [image: You are viewing an attached message. Gmail can't verify the authenticity of attached messages.] that is not genuinely part of the message
   5. Seek message Print command: find it ABSENT!
   6. Try browser print, accepting that result will be inauthentic: find result includes only page 1 regardless of print settings!

Answer (score -1):

Successful workaround 1: First disengage Conversation View! This is kind of unsurprising, but Wow, one message's *printed content* gets discarded by a *display setting* for the *conversation*??! What were you thinking, Gmail Designer? :)

Successful workaround 2: First disengage Conversation View and reengage it!! Crazy but true (probably only until browser reload or something.)

PS On Quick Settings use the command at far bottom where you might not have seen it.